# Can't get output right, need same code on different line

Tags: c++, loops, output

Hey so my code works but I need to get this output right, I need it to output the letters I put in 2 times. It will print it once correctly but I added a loop and it bunches the Chars together instead of printing it 2 times in the loop. If I separate it with endl or \n it will separate the chars. I just want it to print the whole  line I enter 2 times

```
{
    char c;
    string s;
    int index = 0;
    cout << "Enter a line:";
    cin.get(c);

    while (c != '\n' && index < size) {
        x[index] = c;
        cin.get(c);

        index++;
    }

    Letter = index;
    cout << "" << Letter << endl;

    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Letter; ++i)
    {
        bool found = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
            if (x[i] == x[j])
                found = true;
        if (!found)
            x[k++] = x[i];
        s = +x[i];
        for (int z = 0; z < 1; z++) {
            cout << "" << s;
        }
    }
Letter = k;
}
```

Comment: its towards the bottom where I have my for(int z=o) I want it to print that 2 times

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  You did use a debugger before posting?  Right?

Comment: oh yes, I just posted the function. how do I post my debugger?

Comment: `for (int z = 0; z < 1; z++)` loops only 1 time.  Replace `1` with `2` to loop twice. Also, your whole `while` loop at the beginning can be replaced with a single call to either `std::getline()` or `std::cin.getline()` depending on whether `x` is a `std::string` or `char[]` respectively. And FYI, `<< ""` is a no-op, you don't need it, so you should get rid of it.

Comment: so I did that and I input some thing abd eoosd and itll output aabbdd eeoooossdd, I want it to output abd eoosd (Newline) abdeoosd

Comment: What is the point of your searching for identical characters? It doesn't have any relation to your stated problem, "to print the whole line I enter 2 times".

Comment: After using the debugger, you can highlight the statement causing the issue, with comments.  Please describe in your post how the highlighted statement is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To read a line and print it twice:

```
std::string line;
if (std::cin.getline(line))
{
    std::cout << line << '\n' << line << '\n';
}
```